# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "DATETIME"."DATETIME": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, python-2.7, cx-oracle, python-datetime

I'm trying to export an Oracle DB with Python's cx_Oracle. I connect to DB, query all of the rows I need, and then build an INSERT statement with them.
I'm using code similar to this:

```
table_name = "AUDIT"
where_clause = "id > 10"
query = "SELECT * FROM " + table_name + " WHERE " + where_clause
curs = db_conn.cursor()
curs.execute(query)
res = curs.fetchall()
columns = []
for i in range(0, len(curs.description)):
    columns.append(curs.description[i][0])
column_names = ",".join(columns)
statement = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES %s" % (table_name, column_names, row)
print statement
```

The types are NUMBER,VARCHAR2,DATE,NUMBER, and I get an insert statement that looks good... except for the date field:

```
INSERT INTO AUDIT_LOG (LOG_DBID,USER_NAME,EVENT_DATE,SEVERITY) VALUES ('AUDIT_LOG_SQ.nextval', 'user@do',datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 28, 1, 57, 42), '1')
```

When I try to execute this, whether via sqlplus or the same cursor, I get the following error:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
INSERT INTO AUDIT_LOG (LOG_DBID,USER_NAME,EVENT_DATE,SEVERITY) VALUES ('AUDIT_LOG_SQ.nextval', 'SYSTEM@do',datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 28, 1, 57, 42), '1')
Error at Command Line:1 Column:95
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DATETIME"."DATETIME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Without the datetime element the queries work just fine. 
**How do I insert a result I got from a cursor?**

I checked SQL_Developer exports to compare with mine, and they have a different way of handling it:

```
INSERT INTO AUDIT_LOG (LOG_DBID,USER_NAME,EVENT_DATE,SEVERITY) VALUES ('AUDIT_LOG_SQ.nextval', 'user@do',to_timestamp('25-APR-18','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'), '1')
```

Which I haven't really found a way to duplicate (without turning the whole query into an ugly string concatenation), and I'm not sure I need to - there must be something I'm missing!

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to do what you're doing, but - as for 5 hours there are no answers, let me say a word or two.

This is a statement that failed:

```
INSERT INTO AUDIT_LOG (LOG_DBID,USER_NAME,EVENT_DATE,SEVERITY) VALUES 
('AUDIT_LOG_SQ.nextval', 'SYSTEM@do',datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 28, 1, 57, 42), '1')
```

What do you expect `datetime.datetime` to be? To me (and, presumably, Oracle), it looks as if it there's user whose name is `datetime` (the first one, in front of the dot) which has a function named `datetime` (the second one, behind the dot). Most probably neither of these two is true, is it?

I'd suggest you to try with the TO_DATE function which would accept two parameters: date (and time) and appropriate format mask, such as

```
to_date('2018-04-28 01:57:42', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

You'd put that instead of your `datetime` construct.

However, I'm afraid that - even if you do that - `INSERT` might fail once again because of the first value you're inserting.

`LOG_DBID` looks like an `ID` (`NUMBER` datatype); is it? `INSERT` you wrote is trying to insert a string into it - because you enclosed it into single quotes: `'audit_log_sq.nextval'`. `AUDIT_LOG_SQ` is a sequence name. So, if you want to insert a numeric value into that column, you should omit single quotes.

Finally, statement that *might* work (at least, in Oracle itself) would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO AUDIT_LOG (LOG_DBID,USER_NAME,EVENT_DATE,SEVERITY) VALUES 
(AUDIT_LOG_SQ.nextval, 
 'SYSTEM@do', 
  to_date('2018-04-28 01:57:42', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 
 '1')
```

I hope it makes sense, even in your context.

Comment: @a.pet as well as the above, make sure you use bind variables, which are critical for performance and security reasons.  See examples such as https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/BindInsert.py  You can using bind variables with `to_date` like `to_date(:bv, 'yyyy-mm-dd')` etc.

Comment: @Littlefoot Thank you so much for noticing the .nextval problem! Too bad I only saw it now (I eventually solved it from home but was yet to update the question), but in short - the problem was both the sequence represented as string and _values that are null - python writes them down as None (obviously), and then the insert fails because SQL is unaware of what is None._
I also replaced all the datetime.datetime with to_timestamp eventually(I had to use regex, since it was in a string by the time I can change it) and it works fine now.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DATETIME"."DATETIME": invalid identifier

You get this error because `datetime.datetime` is not valid Oracle syntax. You sort of know that, because you know how Oracle SQL Developer formats timestamps. But you're don't want to replicate the explicit `to_timestamp()` logic.

It's not clear to me where you're getting the values of EVENT_DATE from, but given that this is an audit function maybe what you need is `sysdate` , an Oracle built-in which gives us the current date and time.